# House built in 2010 - where's the grounding rod?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, grounding, grounding-and-bonding

This is the main panel outside the house (a subpanel is inside the house right behind it). I was wondering where the grounding rods are (I think they've been required by code for a while?), but I can't find them. I see the ground wire is bonded to the neutral that comes from the power pole on the street. But don't I need two grounding rods? Seeing as the house was built fairly recently in 2010, is there some new method where grounding rods are not easy to locate? I'm thinking a house built this recently must have grounding somehow seeing as it passed city inspection.... Thank you.

EDIT: I'm attaching a 2nd photo showing the right half of the panel. Unfortunately, I can't open it. I think only the power company can open it. But as you can see, the only thing going into the right half of the panel is the pipe at the top, which is the weatherhead. The ground wire at the top of the panel is connected to the cable TV wire. Is it possible that there's a ground wire going into the main panel from behind?

By the way, the ground wire shown in the first photo (which connects to the sub-panel inside the house) used to be connected to the left side of the panel where you see those two unused holes now. Is it possible that there's something inside the wall connecting to ufer ground?

EDIT2: Adding a photo of the sub-panel inside the house, behind the main panel.

[image: Main panel]
[image: Right half of the main panel]

[image: Inside of sub-panel inside the house behind the main panel]

Comment: 2010 I would expect a concrete encased "Ufer" ground, but I don't see the connection. https://constructioninspectiontips.com/ufer-ground-requirements/

Comment: Who do you have for your electric utility, and can you post a photo showing the whole meter-main square on?

Comment: Let's have a look in the main panel too. The grounding electrode conductor shouldn't land there -- but that's not the same as _doesn't_ land there! Also have a look around the area for any electrical junction boxes with a blank cover plate, on the interior or the exterior. If there is a ufer ground, the clamp connecting the grounding electrode conductor to the stub of rebar is likely to be accessible through such a box.

Comment: Below your boxes there is a bare copper wire I can’t tell where it goes or the size but it may be your the conductor to your ground rod or cement encased (ufer) ground. If the wire goes to a rod it should be #6 if the wire goes to a ufer ground it should be #4, the grounds can be larger. It may be landed in your meter side not totally unheard of.

Comment: Thanks everyone! I added a new photo showing the right half of the main panel. Unfortunately, I can't open it. I added some additional details in the post above. Is it possible there's grounding connection inside the wall behind the panel somehow?

Comment: @K.Don -- who do you have for an electric utility? (That way, I can pull up their service specs and see if they require the installer to do funny business, like landing the grounding electrode conductor in the meter socket enclosure)

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel sorry I missed that. I have Pacific Gas & Electric (PG&E).

Comment: Can you get us photos of the interior of the subpanel please?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel sure! Just added the only photo I have of the inside of the sub-panel. Not sure if it shows you what you need to see. The green ground wire from the main panel outside comes into the sub-panel, then goes to the Tesla Backup Gateway on the left side, and then comes back into the sub-panel.

Comment: @K.Don -- yeah, we'll need square-on shots of both the backup gateway and the subpanel to unravel this fully